# When enlarging an Image using Transform.scale, the parent widget is also enlarged accordingly

Tags: flutter, dart

As follows, the Image widget is scaled to 1.2 times and returned to the caller. However, by doing so, the size of the parent widget is also scaled to 1.2 times. I would like to scale only the Image widget to 1.2 times and keep the size of the parent widget as it is.

Is it possible to achieve this?

```dart
SizedBox(
  height: 400,
  width: 500
  child: convertImage(),
);
```

```dart
  Widget convertImage() {
    return Transform.scale(
      scale: 1.2,
      child: Image.memory(_image, fit: BoxFit.cover),
    );
```

Comment: can you share the code which include parent widget.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added a parent widget.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use the 'Transform' image, the Image.network widget has scale property inbuilt -

```
Widget convertImage() {
    return Image.memory(
      '_image',
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      scale: 1.2,
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had already tried that, but I couldn't enlarge it.

Comment: Then use 'fit' property or 'height & width' property to enlarge the image.